# RED5 open-source chat :"Scope rtmpclient not found on localhost"

Tags: red5

i tried to make this opensource RED5 project work for many days but without success - http://www.camrumble.com/source/opensource_chatroulette_5.jsp  . Iam using RED5 1.0 RC1. I have done everything according to the tutorial, I start debugging my red5 server under eclipse, then I run my flex project in flash builder, it opens up a browser with the chat window, but it just says that:

```
Initialize connection
NetConnection.Connect.Rejected
Connection error, please refresh the page.
```

When I look then to Console in Eclipse theres just this:

```
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope rtmpclient not found on localhost
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 55783 to localhost (in: 3337 out 3217 ), with id 1 due to long handshake
```

Where could be the problem? It looks like to me, it cant find those files? But they are in the webapps directory of the RED5 server so i dont know...

Comment: im facing the same problem, i cant event get the firstapp to work as im getting the same error. Have you fixed this yet?

Comment: Trikam - no i haven't, i tried other versions of RED5, i changed paths, names etc. with no success.  Please, let me know if you find something because I really need it to work (i have a VPS for this and its not used now, because i cant get this to work not even on my computer...)

Comment: this is driving me crazy, ive been trying to get this firstapp running for 2 days. Here is an article i found, it didnt help me but might have an answer for you. Let me know how you get on. http://old.nabble.com/Scope-firstapp-not-found-on-server-td27026470.html

Comment: Yes, I found the same page through google, but it did not help me. I tried the .xml files that are automatically created in eclips (so should work?) and also those from the page in my original post with the same result - scope ... not found. Also I dont have any red5.jar in the director, so this cant be a problem for me. And yes, its driving me crazy too, i have tried it MANY times with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers did not work for me.  Here's what I did:

I followed the tutorials and searched everywhere...  This is my checklist to get it working on ubuntu 11.04:

- Red5 server up and running (http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Install)
- Demos Installed and running (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=969cmyGu1yw)
- Shutdown server (good tutorial on install http://www.videochat-scripts.com/installed-red5-08-rc3-with-jdk-1613-on-linux/)
- Started over with Red5 developer series: Excellent! (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9B94807E1D0AF2DE)
- Place myApp under webapps folder (/home/red5/dist/webapps/myApp)
- Edit the red5-web.properties file (/home/red5/dist/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF):

  ```
   webapp.contextPath=/myApp
   webapp.virtualHosts=*, localhost, localhost:8088, 127.0.0.1:8088
  ```
- Place myAppClient.swf in ROOT directory (since I knew the demos folder was working I put it there, with an html file to call the swf file -- /home/red5/dist/webapps/root/demos)
- Restarted the server: http://localhost:5080/demos/myAppClient.html works!

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

instead of

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

Comment: I believe they are referring to red5-web.xml.  This solution doesn't work on red5 v1.0 after restart.

Answer (score 1):

Gracie's solution seems to be pasted backwards. The solution for me was to make the following adjustment to red5-web.xml:

Change:

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

To:

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

There is, basically, a namespace change. WebScope is no longer encapsulated in a scope folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i managed it finally. The problem was, that i have not changed the .xml files which were created by eclipse automatically. I assumed they were correct. But there was one problem. In the red5-web.xml file there was:

```
<!-- Defines the web handler which acts as an applications endpoint -->
<bean id="web.handler" class="org.red5.core.Application" singleton="true" />
```

Because there was a sample Application file when i created the project in Eclipse. All that was needed was to change it (in my case):

```
class="org.red5.core.Application"
```

to

```
class="org.red5.core.RTMPClientExtended"
```

I also used RED5 0.91 now (dont know if this chat app works in another version).

Answer (score 0):

in my case:
make sure the project has build,if your code is generated by the red5plugin and the eclipse is not enable automatic build,when you deploy the red5 application,the calsess folder is empty,it will reptored the error.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the "scope error" without doing anything special. I logged into my red5 server today, and suddenly found all my apps had stopped working. Tried restarting the red5 which did not work. Finally, I killed the red5 process, and restarted with "red5-debug.sh", instead of red5.sh. It worked and the error is no longer there.